# Change default sender adress when replying to mail in public folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have a public folder in which I receive mail that I need to respond to. When I respond I have the option to choose from 2 different email addresses. The problem is I never need to send from the default address. Every time I respond to an email I need to change the "From" email. 
Is it possible to change the default "From" address?

Comment: When you say "send from the default address", which email is defaulting when you are replying? Is it your main e-mail or the public e-mail. Its not clear based on how you've written your question.

Comment: The default mail is my main e-mail. But I never have to send with that mail.

Comment: Can the public folder be a separate e-mail account you add into Outlook?